# Netbeans 7.4 cordova.js missing

Tags: netbeans, cordova, netbeans-7.4

When i create a new Cordova Application in Netbeans, after the Project has been created, the cordova.js file is missing in the www folder of the project.
The project creation log says: "cordova library for "www" already exists. No need to download. Continuing."

When i start the project in any browser, the cordova.js is missing, because it hasn't been created while project creation.

When creating a cordova project without netbeans but in console with: "cordova create myapp" there is also no cordova.js file in the www folder...

Anybody an idea why this happens?

PS: npm is correctly installed and the cordova version is 3.1.0-0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is created on build action for particular target platform (android/ios/wp...) and added to the project

Comment: Sad but true - a platform-agnostic tool that requires a target platform build